# WCF Client throws error of System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException while using Self sign in Certificate Validation

Tags: wcf, client-server, wcf-security, self-signed-certificate

I'm validating the WCF service with self-signed certificates at the server end. When I consume it at client it throws me an error of

> **System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:** 'An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.'
> **Inner Exception:** FaultException: At least one security token in the message could not be validated.

For Development I am using server and client at the same machine.
Web.Config File for WCF Service(Server) is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><configuration><appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WCF.MyServiceBehaviour">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="8dbd4b4c95df218c448cc2992e9a5863d9a3d3ff" storeName ="My"/>
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="WCF.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCF.MyServiceBehaviour">
            <endpoint address=""
                                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                                contract="WCF.IService1"
                                bindingConfiguration="BasicHTTPEndPointBinding">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="tempSerCert"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"   />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:65300/service1.svc"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHTTPEndPointBinding">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

App.Config for Client is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="CustomBehaviour" >
                <clientCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="eaa8b0a5c5a84548984d562d4c795951e0badd59" storeName ="My"/>
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <defaultCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="8dbd4b4c95df218c448cc2992e9a5863d9a3d3ff" storeName ="My"/>
                    </serviceCertificate> 
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/WCF/Service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehaviour" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" >
            <identity>
                <dns value="tempSerCert"/>
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I'm using nothing but a default template for generated WCF Application service method on the client-side for development.

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed certificates are not authoritative, you can try to set `certificateValidationMode=None` in the server web.config file to fix this error.

Comment: Thanks for answering..! Can you please make this statement **Self-signed certificates are not authoritative** a little bit more clear .? Do you mean while in the development phase I should set the `certificateValidationMode=None` and when I got certificates provided by Certification Authority I'll set it as it is now .?

Comment: About self-signed certificates are not authoritative: https://www.ssldragon.com/blog/self-signed-ssl-certificates-disadvantages/